# How do I fix discord.js ban command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I can't understand what is wrong in this code.
Error:  Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

```
module.exports = {
name: "ban",
execute(client, message, args) {
    const author = message.member
    const target = message.mentions.users.first()
    const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually `message.mentions.members.first()`

which will then take the first member mentioned in the message

Answer (score 0):

This means that `message` is not a real `Message` object. Make sure in your command handler, the arguments are passed like this:

```js
(client, message, args)
```

In that order. I suspect it might be something like this right now

```js
(message, client, args)
```